# How to screen share in skype 5.0 without webcam?

Tags: skype

I used to use the share screen feature in skype to support people and or show people how to do things...

I've upgraded to version 5.0 for PC, and I can no longer find the screen share option!

Apparently you can use video call to share your screen, however when I press on that it tells me I don't have a webcam.

Do skype 5.0 users need to buy a webcam in order to screen share like they could in previous versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting a call first (not a group one) and you should see Call Sharing on the dark side of the screen as told here: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=622763

It seems to be a bug with video devices in beta versions of skype 5, are you using a stable release?

Comment: Thanks for this - it does turn out you can share screen once you make a voice/video call. It's a shame it was removed from simple IM conversations though! I'm using the latest stable release (5.0.0.152). (PS. it also bugs me that those icons have no tooltips!)